# how to resolve preformance issue in IN Clause SQL Query for huge set of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench, query-optimization

I am trying to query from the huge set of data. query keeps running without any result nor error. the same query I run for a small set of test data works fine.

**Query:**

```
> SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 IN (SELECT distinct(t2.col2)
> FROM table2 t2 Left Join table3 t3 on t2.col1 = t3.col1  WHERE
> t3.col1=value);
```

I am again tried to query for huge set of data with

`SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 = (raw_value);` - single value filter works fine.

`SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 IN ( raw_value, raw_value);` - more then one value filter gives performance issue.

please give me suggestions to improve the performance.

-thank you.

Comment: You can use "EXPLAIN" to help you drill down the problem - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html. At surface level, i'm thinking that the column is not indexed?

Comment: What's the point for the `left join`?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Use text, not images/links, for what can be text. Put everything needed for your question in your post, not just at a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance for large IN() clauses will always be poor - there is no way around that. The solution is to use a JOIN instead of an IN().

What will be way faster is:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      table1 t1
JOIN      table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.col1 = t3.col1
WHERE     t2.col1=value;
```

Also, the `LEFT JOIN` here won't actually do anything, so the optimal form is:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      table1 t1
JOIN      table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
WHERE     t2.col1=value;
```

Make sure you have an indexes on

```
table2 (col1)
table2 (col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see the `left join` in the subquery is not needed, since the filter is on the same column used for the `on` condition: if so, just remove it. And I would recommend phrasing the query with `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 on t2.col2 = t1.col1 and t2.col1 = value)
```

For performance, you want an index on `table2(col1, value)`. An index on `table1(col1)` might also help.

Comment: . . You should be clearer that the `JOIN` is not needed because the filter is on the same column used for the `ON` condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thanks... answer updated - with your own words!